# How to apply tcpdf tamil font by using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I apply this line:

```
 $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', true);
```

but my not getting the exact output.

Comment: Where do you apply that line? Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Answer (score 0):

when using TCPDF library you can make your class by inherit from TCPDF class:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
```

you can override the `footer` and `header` function as you like, and inside these functions you can set your font. but TCPDF contains some fonts if you want add new font you must download it and extract it in `tcpdf/fonts/utils` folder and use it by this way:

```
$ge_hili_light = $this->addTTFfont(MAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT .
'/includes/tcpdf/fonts/utils/ge-hili-light.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$this->SetFont($ge_hili_light, 'B', 12, "", false);
```

where `$this` refer to `MYPDF` class which extend from `TCPDF` class

Comment: Above line is added my page ,but i am getting error.please explain the tcpdf apply the tamil font