# How to apply tamil font in codeigniter tcpdf

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf

I want to set this font my codeigniter page.

`$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 10.5, '', true);`

How to apply tcpdf tamil font by using codeigniter?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555889/how-to-apply-tcpdf-tamil-font-by-using-codeigniter

Comment: check out this link http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use mpdf in my codeigniter project.It's working fine.Tamil font is apply my pdf.

Refer this link:http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrate-mpdf-into-codeigniter-framework/
https://davidsimpson.me/2013/05/19/using-mpdf-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Download the font file that you want to use with `.ttf` extension.
**2**.Put it somewhere in your application's directory (accessible).
**3**.Put this in your tcpdf code that produces the pdf: `$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/yourfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);`
**4**.Run the script once.
**5**.Remove the code snippet used in step 3.
**6**.Use the new font by `$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');`

*Let me know if you can't understand anything. Hope it helps*.